# Remove word from the realpath

Tags: bash, shell

Say I have the directory

```
/home/project/program.c
```

I want to change it to

```
project/program.c
```

I've set the real path as a variable and have tried to remove "/home/" but its still there.

```
fpath="$(realpath $file)" 
ffpath=${fpath//$/home//}
echo "$ffpath"
```

Can someone please provide some tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your shorter solution would be to use the prefix pattern removal:

```
fpath="$(realpath $file)" 
ffpath=${fpath#/home/}
echo "$ffpath"
```

However, if you insist in using the pattern substitution, you have to quote the slashes, as they are special separator characters:

```
fpath="$(realpath $file)" 
ffpath=${fpath/\/home\/}
echo "$ffpath"
```

Answer (score 0):

Following solutions could help you on same. Ideally bash expansion parameters should be enough for this requirement but adding few more solutions too.

```
var="/home/project/program.c"
```

***Solution 1st:*** using `cut`

```
echo "$var" | cut -d"/" -f3-
```

***Solution 2nd:*** Using parameter expansion.

```
echo "${var#*/*/}"
```

***Solution 3rd:***  Using `sed`.

```
echo "$var" | sed 's|\(/[^/]*\)/\(.*\)|\2|'
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `basename` and `dirname`

```
x='/home/project/program.c'
ffpath=$( basename "$( dirname $x)" )"/"$( basename $x )
echo "$ffpath"
```